# visual studio showing error in package.json

Tags: angular, visual-studio

{
    "name": "com.example.dashbordapp",
    "displayName": "DashbordApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
    "main": "index.js",
    "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
    "license": "Apache-2.0",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
    }
},
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3", 
      "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
      "admin-lte": "^2.4.2",
      "angular-datatables": "^4.2.0",
      "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.3",
      "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
      "angular4-material-table": "^0.1.8",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
      "bootstrap3-wysihtml5-npm": "^0.3.3-npm.12",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "datatables.net": "^1.10.11",
      "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.11",
      "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
      "jquery": "^3.3.1",
      "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
      "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
      "ngx-adminlte": "^0.9.3",
      "ngx-ckeditor": "^0.2.0",
      "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In json file you should not add extra trailing commas as in javascript or typescript
Below is the corrected json value

```
 {
      "name": "com.example.dashbordapp",
      "displayName": "DashbordApp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
      "main": "index.js",
      "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
      "license": "Apache-2.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@angular/animations": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/common": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/core": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/forms": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/http": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.3",
      "@angular/router": "^5.0.3",
      "admin-lte": "^2.4.2",
      "angular-datatables": "^4.2.0",
      "angular-froala-wysiwyg": "^2.7.3",
      "angular-webstorage-service": "^1.0.2",
      "angular4-material-table": "^0.1.8",
      "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
      "bootstrap3-wysihtml5-npm": "^0.3.3-npm.12",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "datatables.net": "^1.10.11",
      "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.11",
      "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
      "jquery": "^3.3.1",
      "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
      "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
      "ngx-adminlte": "^0.9.3",
      "ngx-ckeditor": "^0.2.0",
      "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
      "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    }
    }
```